# Remove small details in image python

Tags: python, computer-vision, mask

I have been suffering for a long time over the solution of this problem. I need to remove the multi-colored rings and dots in the image, but keep the dense shapes. I tried to use open cv, iterated over the pixels, but I still can't get rid of the unnecessary from the image. Thanks in advance for the advice.

[image]

Comment: explain (**show**) how this was done?

Comment: Hello. this is done by cutting out part of the image. after the centers have been cut out - the edge remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using erosion/dilation from [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).
Here is a quick example, edit the parameters as needed.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png')
blurred_img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(blurred_img, kernel, iterations=1)
output = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imwrite('output.png', output)
```

[image: resulting image]

Comment: Thanks. indeed, open cv worked well, but I did it a little differently, I changed the original image using dilate.